# Como pegar uma variável dentro de outro arquivo sem executá-lo

Tags: python-3.x

Eu estava escrevendo meu código com vários arquivos, mas deu errado quando precisei de uma variável localizada em outro arquivo, mas sempre que tento isso:

```
from meuarquivo2 import minhavariável
```

Ou isso:

```
import meuarquivo2
```

Ele sempre executa o arquivo desde o começo, tem como eu "pegar" esta variável sem executá-lo?

Comment: Ao importar um módulo você já está executando o arquivo, se o seu arquivo só tem variáveis, qual o problema dele criar todas elas? Se você quiser ter o controle maior destas variáveis, pode criar uma classe e você usará ela apenas quando precisar, no entanto, cuidado para não instanciar mais de uma vez e perder as mudanças de valores, se tiver.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Acredito que isso seja impossível. Segundo o que está disponível na documentação do python([neste link](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#loading)), o sistema de importação executa o módulo que está sendo importado.

Minha sugestão é a seguinte: Se as variáveis que deseja são constantes, crie um arquivo separado com as variáveis constantes que deseja importar.

Ex.:

> Por exemplo, crie um arquivo constants.py com o conteúdo

```
minhavariável = 'algum valor'
```

> Então, no arquivo que deseja importar faça o seguinte:

```
from constants import minhavariável
```

Assim, a única execução de código que vai ocorrer é a inicialização dessas variáveis.

Caso não sejam constantes, você pode escrever algumas funções responsáveis pela atribuição de valores dessas váriaveis e colocar em algum arquivo separado para importar. Assim, você importa somente a função desejada sem necessáriamente executá-la.

ex.:

> Por exemplo, crie um arquivo funcs.py com o conteúdo

```
def minha_func(parametros):
    """Aqui você insere seu código"""
    pass# e retira o pass depois que escrever o código
```

> Então, no arquivo que deseja importar faça o seguinte:

```
from funcs import minha_func
```

Após, é só executar minha_func normalmente quando precisar:

```
minha_func(passa_os_parametros_definidos)
```

Comment: Por favor, adicione mais detalhes para expandir sua resposta, como um código que funcione ou citações de documentação.